# SQL Parsing HTML table into data columns

Tags: sql, parsing

I need to parse a column containing some text and HTML table in the following format (5 mln. rows of this marvel):

```
<div>Some smart text with number 148974751</div>
<div>
<table border="1" > 
<th>Header col 1</th> 
<th>Header col 2</th> 
<th>Header col 3</th> 
<tr> 
<td>ParName 1</td>
<td>Date Value</td>
<td>Date Value
</td>
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>ParName 2</td>
<td>Int value</td>
<td>Ubt value</td>
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>ParName 3</td>
<td>String value</td>
<td>String value
</td>
</tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

So there are always 3 columns, first `<td>` contains always string, second and third some valude (date, datetime, int, numeric, string). There are 1 to approx 8 `<tr>` rows in each processed database row.
I searched the forum and from bits and pieces have some idea, that the best approach would be to create a function to process a row at a time.
The function would probably take the HTML code and turn it into an XML and then process a simple logic over the rows and cells.

To start with, I guess I should cast the HTML to XML:

```
SELECT CAST(htmlCell as xml) as XMLcode INTO #TMP FROM SrcTable;
```

This seems to work. Then get the cell values (for start only as string is OK, no need to resolve Int/numeric/bit/... values):

```
SELECT xmlCode.value('(*/td)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') FROM #TMP
```

This doesn't work, I'm already lost. I need to retrieve a content from a `<td>` cells, including column index.

Finally I'd do something along these lines:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (ParamName, StringValue) SELECT ParamName, StringValue FROM #TMP;
```

Comment: if you can avoid it, don't parse html in SQL. There are HTML parsing libraries to tokenize html, so maybe you can do a CLR solution if you can't create a client app to do this for you.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, it's not an ideal procedure. However, the source is in database and the target is a database, so it seemed to me the easiest way to process it in the SQL. Another possibility (due to infrastructure) for me is a standalone VB.NET application, but I would have to implement batch processing (to avoid millions of transaction or too bloated transactions) and retrieving data from DB, processing it and storing back is a long way around... So I consider it a plan B for the moment.

Comment: I would consider plan b. it is not really feasible or ideal to process HTML using SQL. Is all of your html guaranteed to be fully and properly formed? if not, you're opening yourself up for a world of pain. That said, you can still do CLR processing, which keeps it at the DB leve, but you are processing with a language designed for string parsing and handling.

Comment: No, there are few versions (2 or 3) of tables and at least one revision of format. CLR sounds good right from the start, but I am not familiar with it and have no space to get to know it, unfortunately. So the easiest way for me might be to write a little batch processor. If you sum your two suggestions into an answer ant there will be no other solutions, I will accept it as an answer in a day or two. Thank you for your comments.